# Can you buy specific cards with gold?

Tags: hearthstone

I was wondering if it is possible to buy specific cards in Hearthstone with gold.

Is this possible?

Comment: Technically, no, but you *can* buy packs with gold and then disenchant/craft. This gives you an exchange rate of approximately 100 dust per 100 gold (and thus 1600 gold to craft a specific legendary). You should note, though, that 1) if you're just starting, that's a horridly inefficient way of getting that legendary you want, and 2) you only get ~100 dust per pack *on average*; you're only *guaranteed* 40 dust per pack.

Comment: @IainGalloway That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: It felt too short to be an answer to me, particularly since there are already several good-quality answers. One of them can edit it in if they want to save it for posterity :)

Answer (score 12):

No, this is not possible.

Cards can be disenchanted for Arcane Dust, which can be used to craft specific other cards. The amount of arcane dust granted depends on the rarity of the destroyed card, as does the price of the crafted card.

- Common - 5 from disenchant, 40 to craft
- Rare - 20 from disenchant, 100 to craft
- Epic - 100 from disenchant, 400 to craft
- Legendary - 400 from disenchant, 1600 to craft

Golden cards are more expensive to craft and worth more when disenchanting.

- Golden Common - 50 from disenchant, 400 to craft
- Golden Rare - 100 from disenchant, 800 to craft
- Golden Epic - 400 from disenchant, 1600 to craft
- Golden Legendary - 1600 from disenchant, 3200 to craft

Comment: note that golden cards don't do anything better than regular cards. their pictures just have animations.

Answer (score 7):

Yes! You can buy certain specific cards with gold!

Specifically, if you spend 700 gold to unlock the League of Explorers adventure, you gain two copies each of Explorer's Hat and Forgotten Torch, with no other requirements.

Additionally, for all adventures, you can spend gold to unlock AI enemies to face, which reward cards the first time beating them, and additional cards on completion of each "wing"

Otherwise, no. Packs are purchasable with gold, which can contain any card from their set. Individual cards can only be bought ("crafted") with a separate Dust currency, acquired from "disenchanting" cards you already possess.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't purchase specific cards directly with gold. The only ways to obtain cards are:

1. Leveling up each class (for basic class cards)
2. Opening packs for 5 random cards from that set
3. Rewards for completing single-player adventures
4. Rewards at the end of an Arena run
5. Rewards at the end of a season (based on rank)
6. Crafting cards with dust

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to outright buy cards with gold.  You can acquire cards through packs, adventures, or leveling up and receiving class cards.  The closest you can get to spending gold would be to buy packs of cards and convert them to dust within your collection.  You can then craft the cards you want.